# Is it possible to reset --hard with ansibles git module?

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to do a reset --hard with ansible? 
Without using command: if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`git reset` is a command that modifies the tree, like `merge`, `commit`, `rebase`, and a number of others.  Those aren't actions that you generally want to perform in a server configuration or application deployment process, and so aren't covered by [the `git` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/git_module.html).

Why are you wanting to use `reset`?

If necessary, you can always fall back to using the `command` module:

```
- command: git reset --hard origin/master
  args:
    chdir: /my/repo/path
```